# Unable to set my state variables using this.setState() which is called through onClick()

Tags: reactjs, html5-canvas

I am getting the mouse coordinates when the mouse is clicked on canvas element through onClick={this.handleClick}. In handleClick method, I'm calculating the coordninates as "xaxis" and "yaxis" and setting these values to state variables "x" and "y" through setState. Im getting the predefined values shown instead of calculated values.

```
import React from "react";
import "./Canvas.css";

export default class Canvastest extends React.Component{

constructor(){
    super()
    this.state={
        x:0,
        y:0
    }       
}

 handleClick=(e)=>{

    console.log("test");
    const canvas = this.refs.cvs;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    let rect =canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    let xaxis = e.clientX - rect.left;
    let yaxis = e.clientY - rect.top;
    console.log("xaxis : "+xaxis);
    console.log("yaxis : "+yaxis);

    this.setState({x:xaxis});
    this.setState({y:yaxis});
    console.log(this.state.x);
    console.log(this.state.y);  
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(xaxis, yaxis, 6, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.save();      
  }


  render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <canvas ref="cvs" height="300" width="300" onClick= 
              {this.handleClick}></canvas>

        </div>
    );
  }
 }


 actual results : 
 test
 Canvastest.js:24 xaxis : 88
 Canvastest.js:25 yaxis : 102
 Canvastest.js:29 0
 Canvastest.js:30 0
 Canvastest.js:18 test
 Canvastest.js:24 xaxis : 201
 Canvastest.js:25 yaxis : 169
 Canvastest.js:29 88
 Canvastest.js:30 102

 Expected results : 

 test
 Canvastest.js:24 xaxis : 88
 Canvastest.js:25 yaxis : 102
 Canvastest.js:29 88
 Canvastest.js:30 102
 Canvastest.js:18 test
 Canvastest.js:24 xaxis : 201
 Canvastest.js:25 yaxis : 169
 Canvastest.js:29 201
 Canvastest.js:30 169
 so on...
```

Comment: Do you mean you get predefined values in ‘consol.log(this.state.x)’ right after you setState? Please keep in mind that setState is asynchronous

Comment: I would first join the two setState methods to be this: `this.setState({ x: xaxis, y: yaxis })` and you are also trying to access the state immediately after setting it. Try doing `console.log(this.state)` in your render method. I think you are trying to log the state values before the life cycle actually happens.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected as you are trying to output the values before the setState function finished setting new values. Try below to see the updated values.
You can set your state in one go as below.

```
this.setState({x:xaxis,y:yaxis},()=>{
    console.log(this.state.x);
    console.log(this.state.y);
});
```